# If I passed +200 rep per day, how do I still see my upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I passed +200 reputation today on SO, my second time ever... [eyes glitter]

Anyway, I see I got the +200, but - I'm still getting the occasional upvote here are there. I mean, I think I am, because usually I do.

How do I see my upvotes (on questions, answers and comments) beyond the +200 daily cap?

Comment: The exact same way you'd see them *without* having hit the cap...

Comment: @Servy: But I only see the first +200 in my "recent achievements" list.

Comment: There won't be a rep change, but it'll still be in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can see it in your [reputation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation). It's an 'upvote' event without reputation gain:

[image]